# VSCode Find all references that do not contain a certain character

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, regex-lookarounds

How do I find all instances across my files that contain `< relref "` and do not contain a `/` or `#` after the initial `"`.

I've tried using regex lookaheads, i.e., `< relref "((?!/).)*` but they aren't supported in VSCode

In simpler terms:

```
These should match:

{{< relref "blog/foo.md" >}}
{{< relref "blog/2018/10/09/foo.md" >}}
{{< relref "bar.md" >}}



These should not match:

{{< relref "/bar.md" >}}
{{< relref "#anchor" >}}
{{< relref "/foo/bar.md" >}}
```

Comment: What is wrong with `< relref "[^/#]`? If you are going to replace something use capturing groups `(< relref ")([^/#])` and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: Are the unwanted characters always right after the quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, assuming that you want to match everything from `{{` to `}}`:

`{{< relref "[^\/#][^"]*" >}}`

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know that lookahead support was added in v1.29, [backreferences and lookahead in regex searches](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_backreferences-and-lookahead-in-search).